# Support for "Always Encrypted" feature of SQL Server using Delphi Components

Tags: delphi

Used TADOConnection with driver MSOLEDBSQL.1 driver to connect to a Database in SQL Server. One of the column in a table in that database is set to use "Always Encrypted" option.
Even after adding "ColumnEncryption=Enabled" & "Trust Server Certificate=True" to the connection string still I can see only encrypted data.

Am I missing any other setting in the connection string?

When connected to the same DB from "SSMS" by adding "Column Encryption Setting = Enabled" in Additional Connection Parameters, I can see the actual column data. When connected Without the "Column Encryption Setting" option only encrypted data is being displayed.

Comment: Please put a minimum of effort into a question by ending it with a question mark instead of a dot. Also elaborate on your own attempts so far.

Comment: From Delphi it is basically the ODBC driver for SQL Server that provides the support, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-client-development?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @AmigoJack, I have clearly asked a question "Am I missing any other setting in the connection string?", I don't know how you missed it.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, I understand that it is all about the driver but even after having the latest ODBC Driver i.e. ODBC Driver 18.3 which actually supports "Always Encrypted". But still I am seeing only encrypted values always in the Application. I really doubt that does ADO Support this because I am using ADOQuery/ADOTable?

Comment: Watch the date of my comment and compare that to [your first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71911311/1), not the current one edited 3 months later. At that time there was no question and hardly any content.

Comment: @AmigoJack, yeah got you. I am sorry for that. Hope now you have enough information and the exact problem I am facing.